# Photoshop: How do you make a blur not go over a layer under it without changing the layers level?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

### Photoshop: How do you make a blur not go over a layer under it without changing the layers level???

I remeber doing this on Photoshop but I can't remeber how to do it or I just did it a different way and forgot but I have looked every where and kind find anything about this.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi Ashley and welcome to GDSE. I don't fully understand your question. Please elaborate a little bit. "Blur" is normally an *effect*. Is it the dark lines you are calling "a blur"? Are they just on a normal layer? Does "without changing the layer levels" mean that you won't move the layers? If so then why? Please post an image of your *Layers* panel. Do you perhaps want to confine the lines to only be on top of the light square? Or do you want the light square to be unaffected by the lines?

Comment: I don't want to change the layers but I want to confine the blur(which is the darker lines) to the shape so that they don't go over the shape.

Comment: So no lines on the light square? Why can't you just move the white square above the lines?

Comment: I want the blur inside the square I just don't want the blur to go outside of the square

Comment: .. add a layer mask....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how your document is set up. If the light square is on a separate layer and has transparent background, you could do one of the following two things:

### Create a *Clipping Mask*

- Place the mouse cursor between the layer with the lines and the layer with the square which you want to confine the lines to.
- Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and left click.

[image]

### Create a *Layer Mask*

- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> and left click the layer with the square to select all non-transparent pixels of that layer.
- Select the layer with the lines and click the *Add layer mask* button.

[image]